# osX strange behaviour when turning on ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I have a osX application which has a window which contains a NSViewController which contains a NSTabView.

Tabs are dynamically  created and each NSTabViewItem (inherited) contains a NSView which I create with another NSViewController (inherited) this view has a button which Has an IBAction called “btnPressed” selector in the NSViewController.

When I an not using ARC i Get to my breakpoint just fine but as soon as I switch ARC on and I press the button I get an access violation.

here are some assumptions I am making.

the view in the tabitem will keep the  NSViewController alive until the tab is closed.

the Views FileOwner will be the NSTabviewController.

my guess is that when I switch ARC on somehow the ViewController released so when I press the button it access invalid memory.

it the strategy ?

what is the best way to track down access violations when using ARC ?.

Is there a way to have a breakpoint on object deallocation when using arc ?

regards Christian Andersen

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: I get a exc_bad_access code 1 in nsapplicationmai

Comment: I have worked out that the viewcontroler is getting disposed pretty much as soo and seen as as it is crested I thought that the view would keep it alive but for some reason it is not eventhough I added the I added it to an array it will try to add it to a specialise version to the NSTabViweItem and see what happens